# Delete an element from array nuxtjs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to delete an element from array but if i make 3 posts and i try deleting them the last one that remains is usually one that has already been deleted. Until I refresh.

```html
<tr class="border-b" v-for="(post, i) in posts.data" :key="i">
  <td class="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-base whitespace-nowrap p-4 text-left flex items-center">
    {{ post.title}}
  </td>
  <td class="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-base whitespace-nowrap p-4">{{ post.excerpt}}</td>
  <td class="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-base whitespace-nowrap p-4">{{ post.updated_at }}</td>
  <td class="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-base whitespace-nowrap p-4"><NuxtLink :to="'/posts/edit/'+ post.id">Edit</NuxtLink></td>
  <td class="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-base whitespace-nowrap p-4 delete"
  @click="deletePost(post.id)"
  >
  <i class="fa fa-trash mr-2 text-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
  middleware: 'auth',
  components:{
    LeftBar,
    TopBar,
    Footer 
  },
  data: () => ({
    posts: []
  }),
  async fetch(){
    const response = await this.$axios.get('/api/posts')
    this.posts = response.data
  },
  methods: {
    deletePost(id){
      this.$axios.delete('/api/post/delete/' + id)
      .then(() => {
        if(id){
          this.posts.data.splice(this.posts.data.indexOf(id), 1)
        }
      })
    }
  },
  head(){
    return{
      title: 'All Posts'
    }
  },
}
```

How do i ensure that each element i click is the one deleted?

Comment: Hm I guess you should call `this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(id), 1)` without the `.data`,  since `this.posts` is the array directly.

Comment: Did that already did not work

Comment: Define `did not work`? Is it successful on the backend (in your devtools network tab)? Is it successful in your Vue devtools? What is not working exactly? Btw, rather than trying to find the id in your `deletePost` method, maybe pass directly the `i` (from the `v-for` loop) into the same method. That way, you already have the index.

Comment: @HenryOladeji I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- As `deletePost()` method is responsible to make an API call to delete the selected record from the backend. Then, Why you are deleting that again at client side ? API should response with the filtered data and you can directly assign that in `this.posts`.
- `this.posts.data` is an array of objects and `id` is a number. Hence, `this.posts.data.indexOf(id)` will not work.

Let me explain with a demo **:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title 1',
        excerpt: 'Excerpt 1',
        updated_at: 'Updated 1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Title 2',
        excerpt: 'Excerpt 2',
        updated_at: 'Updated 2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Title 3',
        excerpt: 'Excerpt 3',
        updated_at: 'Updated 3'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Title 4',
        excerpt: 'Excerpt 4',
        updated_at: 'Updated 4'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deletePost(id) {
      // make an API call and bind the response directly in this.posts
      this.posts.forEach((obj) => {
        if (id === obj.id) {
          this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(obj), 1);
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.link {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <td>{{ post.title}}</td>
      <td>{{ post.excerpt}}</td>
      <td>{{ post.updated_at }}</td>
      <td class="link" @click="deletePost(post.id)">Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```